# Is there a way to count how many shared characters are between two strings using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, search, match

I want to be able to compare two typed strings and show how many letters are shared between them.

So for example if one input get's *"dog"* string and the other input get's *"door"* string. it will echo `'2'` (only *"d"* and *"o"* are shared between those two strings).

But also if one string is *"door"* and one string is *"bloom"* it will echo `'2'` (and not `'1'`).

Any ideas of functions that can help with this kind of operation?

Comment: *"Is there a way to count how many shared characters are between two strings using jQuery?"* No. jQuery is a library of DOM manipulation functions (and the occasional utility function), nothing more. JavaScript, the *language* you use it with, can certainly be used for this. Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: If more than 1 character is shared, how will the output be shown ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an object that has a count for each unique letter (a frequency), and then decrease that counter whenever there is a match with a letter in the other input. Only when the counter is still positive will the match be allowed.

That method will also avoid a nested loop, and thus have a better time complexity (remember that `indexOf` represents an internal loop):

```js
$(".1,.2").on("keyup", function() {
    const value1 = [...$(".1").val().toLowerCase().replace(/\s|-/g,'')],
        value2 = [...$(".2").val().toLowerCase().replace(/\s|-/g,'')],
        freq = {};
    value1.forEach(ch => freq[ch] = (freq[ch] || 0) + 1);
    var result = value2.reduce((acc, ch) => acc + (freq[ch] ? !!freq[ch]-- : 0), 0);
    $('.result').text(result + ' letters match!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Write a word: <input class="1"><br/>
And another one: <input class="2"><br/>
<div class="result"></div>
```

#### Explanation

Compared to your code, I have:

- Joined the two replacements into one with `/\s|-/g`: this will match any space or hyphen in one go.
- Split the strings into arrays of characters with the spread operator `[...   ]`. Calling `split` works fine also, but I like this shorter syntax.
- Introduced the variable `freq`. It is a plain object, and gets a property for each individual character. As properties are unique, only one property will exist per unique character.
- The `forEach` loop will create these properties and will assign a number to it that reflects the number of times that particular character occurs in `value1`.
- The expression `(freq[ch] || 0)` first evaluates `freq[ch]`. If `freq` does not yet have a property for that character `ch`, then this will give `undefined`, which is a "falsy" value. Then the logical OR (`||`) will kick in and take 0 as value instead. Then `+ 1` is added to it, so the value will be 1 for the first occurrence. This is then assigned to `freq[ch]`. If on the other hand that property already existed, it will have as value 1 or more, which is a "truthy" value, and so the `|| 0` is not evaluated and `+ 1` is added to the current value. This is a tactic that is often used in JavaScript code. So for the example of "door", `freq` will look like this once the `forEach` has completed:

  ```
  {
      "d": 1,
      "o": 2,
      "r": 1
  }
  ```
- `reduce` is called on `value2`, which just iterates over each individual character in `value2` and returns a *single* value. That value starts out with 0 (the last argument passed to `reduce`), and gets passed to the callback as the first argument `acc`. With a ternary operator we check whether the character exists in `freq`: `freq[ch] ?`. If so, the `!!freq[ch]--` part is evaluated. This looks a bit complex, but really it is not that hard to understand. `freq[ch]--` gives us the value of `freq[ch]` (the number of occurrences in `value1`) and then decrements it (`--`). Important is that the value is retrieved *before* the decrement happens. Then a double negation is applied to that value (`!!`): that turns a number into a boolean: true for non-zero, false for zero. But as we already knew it was non-zero through the ternary operator, this always gives us `true`: This boolean value is then coerced to a number (1) again, because it must be added to `acc`. So we actually add 1 to `acc` when `freq[ch]` is not zero. Then there is the other part of the ternary operator which kicks in when `freq[ch]` is either zero or does not exist at all: in that case we add 0 to `acc` (a no-operation). This expression is returned to the `reduce` internals, which passes it again as `acc` to the next iteration, and so `acc` gets incremented for each matching character. `reduce` returns the last value of `acc` giving us the final result.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i guess i was drunk when i wrote it :)) works great! Thanks!

Comment: It would be great if you could add some explanation comments on the code. Thanks anyway again!

Comment: Added an explanation.

Comment: Amazing. absolutely wonderful! Thanks you very much! learned a lot from this!

Answer (score 0):

So, that's the solution i ended up with (the comments really helped :)

```
var a = "dog";
var b = "door";
var c = a.split("").filter(function(val) {
return b.split("").indexOf(val) != -1;
});
```

`c.length` will now contain the number of shared letters.

Hope it will help some one else also.

Example:

```js
$(".1,.2").on("keyup", function() {
var value1 = $(".1").val().toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'').replace('-','');
var value2 = $(".2").val().toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'').replace('-','');
var result = value1.split("").filter(function(val) {
return value2.split("").indexOf(val) != -1;
});
$('.result').html(result.length + ' letters match!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Write a word: <input class="1"><br/>
And another one: <input class="2"><br/>
<div class="result"></div>
```

- Still if i input "dog" and "door". it will echo '3' and not '2'. so it's not perfectly right yet, but very close.